# Find all the possible combinations of array elements with two attributes where neither repeats

Tags: php, recursion, combinations, combinatorics

I have two arrays:

```
$colors = [ 'gold', 'silver', 'bronze', 'wood' ];
$emotion = [ 'happy', 'sad', 'wow', 'angry' ];
```

Out of those, I can make up 16 elements, so that colors and emotion don't repeat. I can easily generate all the unique elements by nesting 2 `foreach` loops.

```
$items = array();

foreach ( $colors as $c ) {
    foreach( $emotion as $e ) {
        $items[] = array( $c => $e );
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to create a 4x4 grid out of those 16 elements so that every column and every row contains only 1 element with particular color AND emotion.

To further explain, one row, of 4 elements( from the `$items` array ), can only contain one element of each emotion and color. It can not have colors nor emotions repeat in a row. The same goes for column.

What would be the proper way to do it? I'm pretty sure I need some condition checks and recursion, but not sure how to do it.

**EDIT: Add example output**

As for the output, it should be an array of four arrays, 4 elements in each, like so:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["bronze"]=>
    string(5) "angry"
    ["gold"]=>
    string(3) "happy"
    ["silver"]=>
    string(3) "sad"
    ["wood"]=>
    string(5) "wow"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["gold"]=>
    string(5) "happy"
    ["bronze"]=>
    string(3) "wow"
    ["wood"]=>
    string(5) "angry"
    ["silver"]=>
    string(3) "sad"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["silver"]=>
    string(5) "happy"
    ["wood"]=>
    string(3) "sad"
    ["bronze"]=>
    string(5) "angry"
    ["gold"]=>
    string(3) "wow"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["wood"]=>
    string(5) "happy"
    ["silver"]=>
    string(3) "wow"
    ["gold"]=>
    string(5) "angry"
    ["bronze"]=>
    string(3) "sad"
  }
}
```

Here's a( one of ) solution:

```
bronze->angry   |  gold->happy      |  silver->sad      |  wood->wow        
gold->sad       |  bronze->wow      |  wood->angry      |  silver->happy
silver->wow     |  wood->sad        |  bronze->happy    |  gold->angry  
wood->happy     |  silver->angry    |  gold->wow        |  bronze->sad
```

Comment: Yes, i just gave an example of the output. Output itself is does not represent correxlct answer

Comment: There is correct answer. Let me change it to correct answer

Comment: I just edited to show visual solution, at the end of the question

Comment: @milos will the two arrays always be the same length?

Comment: @Mulan which two arrays, materials and emotion? If so, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ok, so you need to first collect all possible pairs as you did.
- Now, we will try to place a pair at a location *if no collision* in the grid and check with other pairs.
- If the current placement fails, we try another location and so on and so forth.

(*Scroll to the end to check with a working demo if you would like to see this in action first*)

**generateGrid:**

```
<?php

function generateGrid($colors, $emotions, &$grid){
    $combs = [];
    foreach($colors as $color){
        foreach($emotions as $emotion){
            $combs[] = [$color, $emotion];
        }
    }

    /* initialize grid */
    for($i = 0; $i < count($colors); ++$i){
        for($j = 0; $j < count($emotions); ++$j){
            $grid[ $i ][ $j ] = [];
        }
    }
    /* initializing grid ends */

    if(makeGrid($combs, $grid, 0, count($colors) * count($emotions))){
        return true;
    }

    $grid = [];// restore the grid to original state
    return false;
}
```

**makeGrid:**

```
<?php

function makeGrid($combs, &$grid, $idx, $total){
    if($idx == $total) return true;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($grid); ++$i){
        for($j = 0; $j < count($grid[ $i ]); ++$j){
            if(count($grid[ $i ][ $j ]) == 0){
                if(noCollision($combs[ $idx ], $i, $j, $grid)){
                    $grid[ $i ][ $j ] = $combs[ $idx ];
                    if(makeGrid($combs, $grid, $idx + 1, $total)){
                        return true;
                    }
                    $grid[ $i ][ $j ] = [];
                }               
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**noCollision check method:**

```
<?php

function noCollision($element, $row, $col, $grid){
    $rowSet = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($grid[ $row ]); ++$i){
        if(count( $grid[ $row ][ $i ]) > 0){
            $rowSet[$grid[ $row ][ $i ][ 0 ]] = true;
            $rowSet[$grid[ $row ][ $i ][ 1 ]] = true;
        }
    }

    if(isset($rowSet[ $element[0] ]) || isset($rowSet[ $element[1] ])){
        return false;
    }

    $colSet = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($grid); ++$i){
        if(count( $grid[ $i ][ $col ]) > 0){
            $colSet[$grid[ $i ][ $col ][ 0 ]] = true;
            $colSet[$grid[ $i ][ $col ][ 1 ]] = true;
        }
    }

    return !(isset($colSet[ $element[0] ]) || isset($colSet[ $element[1] ]));
}
```

**Driver code:**

```
<?php

$grid = [];

if(generateGrid([ 'gold', 'silver', 'bronze', 'wood' ], [ 'happy', 'sad', 'wow', 'angry'], $grid)){
    printGrid($grid);
}else{
    throw new \Exception("No solution found!!");// or whatever you would like to have here
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/10921)

[**Code Demo to print all combinations**](https://wtools.io/paste-code/bE5Y)

Comment: That seems to properly do the job of finding first possible combination. With that being said, I need ALL possible combinations that satisfy the requirements

Comment: @Milos Ok, but do you just want to print them or store them in an array or so?

Comment: that doesn't really matter. What I am looking for is to see a logical solution( and coding one, of course )

Comment: @Milos I updated my answer to print all correct unique combinations possible with a link at the bottom. Looks like there are 6912 solutions possible. So you will need to run this on your machine to check the outputs.

Comment: so I commented out line `34`, and added `echo count( $grid );` at the end of the code. Output is 4. And there's certainly a lot more than 4.

Comment: @Milos I am assuming you are following the code. $grid is just a 4x4 2D array. It is just overwritten each time to print new combination.

Answer (score 0):

We can design an algorithm but your exercise is to write it in PHP. `grid(y,x)` takes columns `y` and rows `x` that holds `y` in place and "rotates" `x` one-by-one -

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gold/ smile | silver/ sad | bronze/ wow | **wood**/ **angry** |
| gold/ sad | silver/ wow | bronze/ **angry** | **wood**/ smile |
| gold/ wow | silver/ **angry** | bronze/ smile | **wood**/ sad |
| gold/ **angry** | silver/ smile | bronze/ sad | **wood**/ wow |

Immutable `rotate(a,i)` of some array `a` and index `i` takes elements up to the index and puts them on the end of the array.

We'll show the implementation in JS because it's easy to demonstrate in the browser and verify the result -

```js
const grid = (y, x) =>
  y.length > x.length // Note below
    ? grid(x, y)
    : x.map((_, i) => Object.fromEntries(zip(y, rotate(x, i))))

const zip = (a, b) =>
  a.length && b.length
    ? [[a[0], b[0]], ...zip(a.slice(1), b.slice(1))]
    : []

const rotate = (a, i) =>
  a.length < 2
    ? a
    : [ ...a.slice(i), ...a.slice(0, i) ]

const colors = [ 'gold', 'silver', 'bronze', 'wood' ]
const emotions = [ 'smile', 'sad', 'wow', 'angry' ]
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(grid(colors, emotions)))
console.table(grid(colors,emotions))
```

`Object.fromEntries` is the JS equivalent of `(object) [ "key" => "value", ... ]` in PHP.

Open your console to view the `console.table` output -

[image: table]

Note, for non-square grids, `x` must be the longer array, otherwise `grid(y,x)` will calculate `grid(x,y)`. Can you reason why this is the case?

Comment: _If_ I understand OP's question correctly, `gold` is present in the first column all the 4 times. I am not sure if he means no duplicate pair or no duplicate entity.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem, perhaps I didn't explain it good enough. Imagine table, 4x4 size, where you need to put 16 elements. Each element can be made of one material( gold, silver, bronze or wood ) and can have one emotion( sad, angry, happy or wow ). None of the elements are made of same combination, so there's one combination for each.

Comment: Now, the task is to put all those elements in the table so that there are no two elements of the same material or two elements of the same emotion in each row or column

Comment: @mulan I updated the question to show viusal example, and an solution

Comment: @milos the last criteria was unclear. this limits the `grid(y,x)` function to inputs where `y.length == x.length`. non-square inputs will have duplication on at least one axis. i can update this post later today to include a modification for this criteria.

Comment: @Mulan You can take a look at updated question. I've added working solution as an example.